# How to add multiple rows with Biztalk DB2 Adapter

Tags: insert, db2, biztalk

I try to insert data in an AS400 database with a Biztalk DB2 adapter.

I deal easily with a one row insertion. However, into the map used on the DB2 adapter, my source schema has a repeatable node. This means that I need, some times, to insert multiple rows at once.

Unfortunately, and for some reasons, I can't use any orchestration ... So what I want to do is to generate a output message looking like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns0:INSERT xmlns:ns0="http://myNamespace">
<sync>
        <after>
            <MyElement id="0" value1="toto" value2="tutu">
            </MyElement>
            <MyElement id="1" value1="toto" value2="tutu">
            </MyElement>
    </after>
</sync>
</ns0:INSERT>
```

This message don't insert anything and leave me with this error :

```
Table MyTable ?MyDataBase ? of *N incorrect for this operation. SQLSTATE: 55019, SQLCODE: -7008
```

(sorry for the translation, the error is initially written in french ...)

I come to a point where I'm asking if it's only possible to do what I want this way ...

Do you have any idea?

Comment: This is normally exactly how you do insert multiple rows into DB2. Supposing your table name is 'MyElement'. How did you generate the schema? The DB2 adapter, in particular, is very keen and restrictive, so be sure to take the exact same setting in your send port as when you generated the schema(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for answers. I find out what went wrong. No link with multiple rows insertion. The way I show it is exactly how you have to insert multiple rows.

The `SQLSTATE: 55019, SQLCODE: -7008` seems to come from the database run time logging which was desactivated.

Now this issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

First, there are no legitimate reasons why Orchestration should ever be prevented.  We can help you clear up any misconceptions they might have on this issue.

However, **MyElement** is an unusual table name.  Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: The legitimate reason for avoid orchestration is that you need to stop the Biztalk application to deploy resources when you have orchestration in it. And in my case, I want to avoid this kind of deployment.

Comment: Then, for **MyElement**, obviously it is not the real name of my table. I use this as an exemple.

Comment: @fcaillaud FYI, what you describe as a reason is **completely untrue**.  You often have to restart Host Instances, not Applications, when deploying, but there's nothing specific about Orchestrations that cause this. *Any* artifact type can require a restart.

Comment: I'm sorry but your changes are linked to an orchestration, then you can need to unlisted this orchestration. To avoid that, you can use [this trick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308958(v=bts.10).aspx) to achieve the deployment correctly.

Comment: @fcaillaud  Well, that's completely different and not really a trick as it applies to Schema, Maps, Pipelines, Pipeline Components equelly.  It's also something most people avoid because when used improperly, SxS brings it's own problems.  Trust me, there are no reasons to avoid Orchestrations that don't equally apply to every other BizTalk Artifact.  Whoever is telling you this has some misconceptions on how BizTalk works.